# Changing a span with no attributes with only CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to write a custom style for a website and am running into a bit of trouble. The following bit of code appears a lot, and I need to remove the float attribute of the span. There are other spans on the page inside `<td>` elements  with floats that must stay untouched, and CSS doesn't have any parent selectors. I can't edit the html in anyway or add any Javascript. What can I do?

```
<table class="forum_post box vertical_margin" id="post00001">
   <tbody>
     <tr class="colhead-dark">
       <td colspan="2">
         <span style="float: left">
           <a class="post_id" href="stuff.com">text</a>
       </span>
     </td>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: side note: 1. `<td>` without `<tr>` ? double check your HTML. 2.  `<tbody>` is optional 3. `<a href>` without `http://` ?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/

Comment: Apologies I retyped all of this. And I know I have to use the !important flag, I'm not sure how to select the <span>

Comment: @Ian Hyzy does my answer work?

Comment: @zer00ne No, and I tried modifying it to fit the new HTML in the post.

Comment: @IanHyzy Ok updated, sir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.box > tbody > tr > td > span { float: none !important; }`

This says:

> Find all
>
> 1. `span`s that are the direct descendant (child) of a...
> 2. `td` which is a child of a...
> 3. `tr` which in turn is a child of...
> 4. `tbody` and finally it being the one and only child of...
> 5. `table`

OR maybe ...

`span[style*="float"] { float: none !important; }`

This says:

> Any `span` with an attribute of `style` containing the word `float`.
>   **[rel *=[external]](https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/)**

Comment: Second answer did the trick, thank you! Can you explain what it does?

Comment: Whoa sorry, spoke a bit too soon. This breaks a lot of stuff on other pages.

Comment: Are you adding this style to a shared external sheet?

Comment: Yes. It applies globally on the site. I just tried your first suggestion again after fixing a typo somewhere else and that seems to have done it. Thanks and sorry for the confusion.